# Rearrange field using meteor-useraccount ionic in Meteor

Tags: meteor, ionic-framework, meteoric

I am doing signUp for my app using [useraccounts:ionic](https://atmospherejs.com/useraccounts/ionic) package, which uses [useraccounts:core](https://atmospherejs.com/useraccounts/core) internally.

I created the form with three field **Full Name**, **Email** & **Password**. In default signUp form **Full Name** field is not there, So, I added like this,

```
AccountsTemplates.addField({
    _id: 'fullname',
    type: 'text',
    displayName: "Full Name",
    required: true
});
```

And i don't want **Confirm Password**. So, removed it.

```
AccountsTemplates.configure({
    confirmPassword: false,
    ....
});
```

But Now i what to rearrange Field. i.e.

```
 |=====================|
 |     Full Name       |
 |=====================|
 |       Email         |
 |=====================|
 |      Password       |
 |=====================|
```

After going through the **meteor-useraccounts/core** [Guide](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/blob/master/Guide.md).

Here is my code:

```
var pwd = AccountsTemplates.removeField('password');
var email = AccountsTemplates.removeField('email');

AccountsTemplates.addField([
    {
        _id: 'fullname',
        type: 'text',
        displayName: "Full Name",
        required: true
    },
    email,
    pwd
]);
```

It is throwing me this `error`:

```
Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'form' of undefined
```

Here is my code at [MeteorPad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/ajWQCxActGWYrM3KJ/UserSignUp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try in the following order

```
AccountsTemplates.addField({
  _id: 'fullname',
  type: 'text',
  displayName: "Full name",
  placeholder: {
    signUp: "Full name"
  },
  required: true,
  minLength: 1,
  trim: true
});

var email = AccountsTemplates.removeField('email');

AccountsTemplates.addField(email);

var password = AccountsTemplates.removeField('password');

AccountsTemplates.addField(password);
```

This is working for me

Comment: ...it works. i have one more query can we modify password field? how can i make custom password validation. i.e. atleast 1 upper case, 1 lower case, 1 digit & 1 special character..?

Comment: I'm not sure but you can use `onSubmitHook:` to check before submiting